# How to assemble ARM SVE instructions with GNU GAS or LLVM and run it on QEMU?

Tags: arm, sve

I want to play with the new [ARM SVE instructions](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0584/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-supplement-the-scalable-vector-extension-sve-for-armv8-a) using open source tools.

As a start, I would like to assemble the minimal example present at: https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0965/latest/getting-started-with-the-sve-compiler/assembling-sve-code

```
// example1.s
    .global main
main:
    mov     x0, 0x90000000
    mov     x8, xzr
    ptrue   p0.s                        //SVE instruction
    fcpy    z0.s, p0/m, #5.00000000     //SVE instruction
    orr     w10, wzr, #0x400
loop:
    st1w    z0.s, p0, [x0, x8, lsl #2]  //SVE instruction
    incw    x8                          //SVE instruction
    whilelt p0.s, x8, x10               //SVE instruction
    b.any   loop                        //SVE instruction
    mov     w0, wzr
    ret
```

However, when I try that on my Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu
aarch64-linux-gnu-as example1.S
```

it does not recognize any of the SVE assembly instructions, e.g.:

```
example1.S:6: Error: unknown mnemonic `ptrue' -- `ptrue p0.s'
```

I think this is because my GNU AS 2.26.1 is too old and does not have SVE support yet.

I'm also fine using LLVM or any other open source assembler.

Once I manage to assemble, I then want to run it on QEMU user mode since [3.0.0 has SVE support](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/ARM/SVE).

Answer (score 1):

**Automated example with an assertion**

- [usage](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/tree/df1e326e4333ea56fa42a4d0d3f6d98ba191cbdd#getting-started)
- [source](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/df1e326e4333ea56fa42a4d0d3f6d98ba191cbdd/v8/sve.S)

Below I described how that example was achieved.

**Assembly**

The `aarch64-linux-gnu-as` 2.30 in Ubuntu 18.04 is already new enough for SVE as can be seen from: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.30/as/AArch64-Extensions.html#AArch64-Extensions

Otherwise, compiling Binutils from source is easy on Ubuntu 16.04, just do:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
cd binutils-gdb
# master that I tested with.
git checkout 4de5434b694fc260d02610e8e7fec21b2923600a
./configure --target aarch64-elf --prefix "$(pwd)/ble"
make -j `nproc`
make install
```

I didn't check out to a tag because the last tag is a few months old, and I don't feel like grepping log messages for when SVE was introduced ;-)

Then use the compiled `as` and link with the packaged GCC on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
./binutils-gdb/ble/bin/aarch64-elf-as -c -march=armv8.5-a+sve \
    -o example1.o example1.S
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -march=armv8.5-a -nostdlib -o example1 example1.o
```

On Ubuntu 16.04, `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` 5.4 does not have `-march=armv8.5-a`, so just use `-march=armv8-a` and it should be fine. In any case, neither Ubuntu 16.04 nor 18.04 has `-march=armv8-a+sve` which will be the best option when it arrives.

Alternatively, instead of passing `-march=armv8.5-a+sve`, you can also add the following to the start of the `.S` source code:

```
.arch armv8.5-a+sve
```

On Ubuntu 19.04 Binutils 2.32, I also learnt about and tested:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-as -march=all
```

which also works for SVE, I think I'll be using more of that in the future, as it seems to just enable all features in one go, not just SVE!

**QEMU simulation**

The procedure to step debug it on QEMU is explained at: [How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembly-in-gdb-on-qemu/51310791#51310791)

First I made the example into a minimal self contained Linux executable:

```
.data
    x: .double        1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5
    y: .double        5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0
    y_expect: .double 8.0, 11.0, 14.0, 17.0
    a: .double        2.0
    n: .word          4

.text
.global _start
_start:
    ldr x0, =x
    ldr x1, =y
    ldr x2, =a
    ldr x3, =n
    bl daxpy

    /* exit */
    mov x0, #0
    mov x8, #93
    svc #0


/* Multiply by a scalar and add.
 *
 * Operation:
 *
 *      Y += a * X
 *
 * C signature:
 *
 *      void daxpy(double *x, double *y, double *a, int *n)
 *
 * The name "daxpy" comes from LAPACK:
 * http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/da4/group__double__blas__level1_ga8f99d6a644d3396aa32db472e0cfc91c.html
 *
 * Adapted from: https://alastairreid.github.io/papers/sve-ieee-micro-2017.pdf
 */
daxpy:
    ldrsw x3, [x3]
    mov x4, #0
    whilelt p0.d, x4, x3
    ld1rd z0.d, p0/z, [x2]
.loop:
    ld1d z1.d, p0/z, [x0, x4, lsl #3]
    ld1d z2.d, p0/z, [x1, x4, lsl #3]
    fmla z2.d, p0/m, z1.d, z0.d
    st1d z2.d, p0, [x1, x4, lsl #3]
    incd x4
    whilelt p0.d, x4, x3
    b.first .loop
    ret
```

You can run it with:

```
qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -E LD_BIND_NOW=1 ./example1
```

then it exits nicely.

Next, we can step debug to confirm that the sum was actually made:

```
qemu-aarch64 -g 1234 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -E LD_BIND_NOW=1 ./example1
```

and:

```
./binutils-gdb/ble/bin/aarch64-elf-gdb -ex 'file example1' \
  -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' -ex 'set sysroot /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu'
```

Now, step up to right after `bl daxpy`, and run:

```
>>> p (double[4])y_expect
$1 = {[0] = 8, [1] = 11, [2] = 14, [3] = 17}
>>> p (double[4])y
$2 = {[0] = 8, [1] = 11, [2] = 14, [3] = 17}
```

which confirms that the sum was actually done as expected.

Observing SVE registers seems unimplemented as I can't find anything under: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/tree/v3.0.0/gdb-xml but it should not be too hard to implement by copying other FP registers? Asked at: http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2018-10/msg00020.html

You can currently already observe it partially and indirectly by doing:

```
i r d0 d1 d2
```

because the first entry of SVE register `zX` is shared with the older `vX` FP registers, but we can't see `p` at all.